# C++ constness by assignment

Tags: c++, reference, constants, const-correctness

I apologize if this question has been answered before, I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

I'm having trouble with keeping const correctness.

I have the following definitions.

```
struct C {
   int x,y;
};

class A {
public:
  C c;      
  C& getC() { return c; }
};

class B {
public:
  void forwardInfo(const A& a) const {
    const C& c = a.getC();  // <= compiler complains here
    daoObject.updateTableX(c.x,c.y);
  }
};
```

The compiler complains that object a is const and therefore can't call a.getC() since that method is not const.

However I'm assigning the result to a const reference. 
Right now I just cast the a object a non const reference like so:

```
const C& c = ((A&)a).getC();
```

This works, but is not elegant. Is there a better way without changing constness. I believe that for object A returning C as not const is reasonable since it is meant to be changed.

Also the forwardInfo should be const since I don't want to change anything.

I'm not sure why the compiler doesn't let me do this and is there a better way?

Ps. I could use getter/setter methods, but class C is meant to be used as a data bucket for passing to a database.

Thank you.

Fixed: bracket location in cast and incorrect cast.

Comment: Casting the result to `const` as you propose won't work. It is the object `a` on which you're calling a non-`const` member that is causing the error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can overload "getC" method like this:

```
C& getC() { return c; }
const C& getC() const { return c; }
```

Comment: I don't think there is a need for overloading, just the second form of the function would be sufficient

Comment: The overload works. Why didn't I think of that.... I do need both forms, since sometimes I do want to change the contents of C. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling a function of `const A&` then you need to declare that function as `const` as well, because the compiler does not know whether the object of `A` will change or not, hence it cannot verify the const-ness of the parameter `const A& a`

```
struct C {
   int x,y;
};

class A {
public:
  C c;      
  const C& getC() const { return c; }
};

class B {
public:
  void forwardInfo(const A& a) const {
    const C& c = a.getC();
    daoObject.updateTableX(c.x,c.y);
  }
};
```

Note the line in class A `const C& getC() const { return c; }`

By using `const`, we tell the compiler that `A::getC()` will not modify the object it is being called on, and so this will work.

Also you need to change the return type of the function as `const`, as that what you require.

Note: You can assign a non-`const` value to a `const` variable, but not the other way around. `const` is an added property that tells the compiler that the value (or refernce address, which is also in a way a value), will not change.

```
      int foo1 = 5;
const int foo2 = 10;

      int& bar1 = foo1; // allowed
const int& bar2 = foo1; // allowed
      int& bar3 = foo2; // NOT allowed -> will give compile time error
const int& bar4 = foo2; // allowed
```